# how to add drop down select menu in my page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As i want to add a drop down select of car models in my app's purchase view , so that user can select only those cars which are present in car table of database.

what should i do for the same ?

thank full to all suggestions !

Comment: your efforts on research?

Comment: <%= f.collection_select(:car_id, Car.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true ) %>

Answer (score 0):

Use [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) helper.

```
select("car", "car_id", Car.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }, { include_blank: true })
```

Comment: i am new in ruby on rails but as u said, i created a select helper and added this code in it , what next?

Comment: Just put the code, @Thaha_kp posted higher to your form

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:id, Car.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true ) %>
```